# How to extract MSEP or RMSEP from lassoCV?

Tags: r, model-evaluations, lasso, mse, ridge-regression

I'm doing lasso and ridge regression in R with the package chemometrics. With `ridgeCV` it is easy to extract the SEP and MSEP values by `modell.ridge$RMSEP` and `model.ridge$SEP`. But how can I do this with `lassoCV`? `model.lasso$SEP` works, but there is no RMSE or MSE entry in the list. However the function provides a plot with MSEP and SEP in the legend. Therefore it must be possible to extract both values! But how?

- SEP = standard error of the predictions;
- MSEP = mean squared error of the predictions;
- RMSEP = root mean square error of the predictions = root(MSEP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chemometrics/chemometrics.pdf) and [the source code of the `lassocv` funtion](https://rdrr.io/cran/chemometrics/src/R/lassoCV.R) the SEP values indeed be extracted from the output using `$SEP`, the MSEP values should be stored in the named list that is returned as `$cv`:

> **Value**
>
> - `cv` - MSEP values at each value of fraction
> - `cv.error` - standard errors for each value of fraction
> - `SEP` - SEP value for each value of fraction
> - `ind` - index of fraction with optimal choice for fraction
> - `sopt` - optimal value for fraction
> - `fraction` - all values considered for fraction

To get the RMSEP you can then simply take the square root of the MSEP values.